# How to populate un-selected values one dropdown to another dropdown in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to populate un-selected dropdown options in table dropdown? and how to get all values in array console?

Im tried but im little struggled with this

> Note: Un-selected options only shown in table dropdown lists

here is my sample code..

**[FIDDLE HERE..](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/yk9zf0c2/)**

```js
var status;
var sno = [];
var load;
var no_rows = 0;
var row;
var mainArr = [];
var tmpArr = [];

function loadValues() {
  var mainTable = $('#tablemain');
  var tr = mainTable.find('tbody tr');
  console.log(tr.length)
  tr.each(function() {
    tmpArr = [];
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {

      var values = $(this).find('input, select').val();
      tmpArr.push(values);

    });
    mainArr.push(tmpArr);
  });
  console.log(mainArr);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add-row").click(function() {
    row = "<tr id=tasklist><td>" + "<input type=text class=sno></input>" + "</td><td>" + "<input type=text class=pname></input>" + "</td><td>" + "<input type=text class=task></input>" + "</td><td>" + "<input type=text class=date></input>" + "</td><td>" + "<select class=status id=dropdown2 name=dropdown2><option >Not Started</option></select>" + "</td><td>" + "<input type=text class=comment></input>" + "</td></tr>";
    $("table > tbody").append(row);
    $('.date').datepicker();
    //  $('.sno').css("background-color","blue");  
    $("select").change(function() {
      status = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
      if (status === "In progress") {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#a1a1ff");
        //$('.task').addClass("blue");
      }
      if (status === "Finished") {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#54c654");
        //$('.task').addClass("green");
      }
      if (status === "Not Started") {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#F8F8F8");
        //$('.task').addClass("white");
      }
    })
    i++;
  });

  $('.load').click(function() {
    loadValues();
  });
});

$('select[name=dropdown1]').on('change', function() {
  $("select[name=dropdown2]").find('option').show();
  var from = $(this).find(":selected").val();
  $("select[name=dropdown2]").val('');
  if (form != "") {
    $("select[name=dropdown2]").find('option:contains("' + form + '")').hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> First Dropdown:
  <select class="status" id="dropdown1" name="dropdown1">
    <option>Not Started</option>
    <option>In progress</option>
    <option>Finished</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
    <input type="button" class="load" value="Enter">
  </form>
  <table id='tablemain' class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>SNo</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Assigned Task</th>
        <th>Due Date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

> Note: Un-selected options only shown in table dropdown lists

Thankyou

Comment: your fiddle is missing libraries, add them first

Comment: Updated now.. please refer that

Comment: still there are errors: datepicker, typo from is `form`, undefined i++;

Comment: Sir, see here https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/yk9zf0c2/

Comment: checkout my answer below. do let me know if anything else you need. glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were few errors.

List of changes:

1. remove i++ which was throwing error being undefined
2. corrected typo `form` instead `from`
3. added options when creating row.
4. added option value in html and js
5. used string literal to create row template
6. hide option based on value.

### Working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7yofb9u1/

### New fiddle:

(When dropdown-1 is having a value initially then on `add row`)

https://jsfiddle.net/oy30pL81/

**Note:** you are using same id for each row dropdown. You can create unique ids per dropdown and not use `dropdown2` and/or add a class to select boxes for jquery selector.

Comment: Yes correct sir, but after selecting dropdown value then only click add row, that time only wants to come unselected values.

Comment: @Joe find second fiddle in answer. :)

Comment: but for my case its not work for me sir, please refer my fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/g356a7wr/

Comment: I dont see a visible `Add row` button in your new fiddle. What is the case ?

Comment: By the way, I see you are adding only blank option in row variable "<option value="">Choose an items</option>", why? add all options here too OR you will need to add them dynamically.

Comment: Add row button is only for Just add the rows dynamically, my problem is only the dropdown - https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/y4j9zqwu/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201133/discussion-between-bilal-siddiqui-and-joe).